# Discordbot doesn't play music with ytdl-core

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I typed in the command in Discord to play music and the bot joins but disconnects a few seconds afterwards from the Voice Channel without playing the music. A few days ago it worked just fine but now it doesn't and I can't find the mistake in the code. I have ffmpeg and opusscript installed so that can't be the mistake. I hope someone can help me:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "$";
const token = "";

function play(connection, message){
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

    server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

    server.queue.shift();

    server.dispatcher.on("end", function() {
        if(server.queue[0]) play(connection, message);
        else connection.disconnect();
    });
}

var servers = {};

bot.on("ready", function(){
    console.log("Ready");
});

bot.on("message", function(message) {
    if(message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    var args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

switch(args[0].toLowerCase()){
    case "play":
        if(!args[1]){
            message.channel.send("Please add a link");
            return;
        }
        if(!message.member.voiceChannel){
            message.channel.send("You have to be in a Voice Channel");
            return;
        }
        if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
            queue: []
        };
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        server.queue.push(args[1]);

        if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection){
            play(connection, message);
        });
        break;
    default:
        message.channel.send("Unknown Command");
        break;
}

});

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Re-watch the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4S2qqX7YvA) and make sure you copied his code correctly, if you have then go into the terminal in your project folder, type in the following:

`npm install`

That will installed all your missing dependencies. 
If you don't have node installed do that (just a quick google search it's easy)

If it still isn't working, I don't know about how to fix it, but considering you're already using someone elses code, [here is another option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-musicbot-addon) it is far superior to Aeirety music bot. It has the following functionalitys:

- play |: Play audio from YouTube.
- skip [number]: Skip a song or multi songs with skip [some number],
- queue: Display the current queue.
- pause: Pause music playback.
- resume: Resume music playback.
- volume: Adjust the playback volume between 1 and 200.
- leave: Clears the song queue and leaves the channel.
- clearqueue: Clears the song queue.

It's also simple to install take a look at it and consider it.

Comment: I tried the Musicbot Addon and now the Bot plays music again. Thank you very much for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue but for whomever meets with this upsetting misfortune in the future, all you have to do is reinstall the ytdl-core module with `npm install --save ytdl-core`. Yeah it's as simple and dumb as that...

Good luck!